# How to set timeout for INSERT query in postgres with MyBatis (Java)

Tags: java, postgresql, mybatis

In Mybatis there is an attribute `timeout` for mapper files but that throws Exception.

```
Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Method org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4PreparedStatement.setQueryTimeout(int) is not yet implemented.
uncategorized SQLException for SQL []; SQL state [0A000]; error code [0]; Method org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4PreparedStatement.setQueryTimeout(int) is not yet implemented.; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Method org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4PreparedStatement.setQueryTimeout(int) is not yet implemented.
........
```

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL doesn't currently support *query* timeouts at the server level. So PgJDBC has a hard time implementing them client-side, though I rather thought current PgJDBC versions emulated it using `statement_timeout`.

Anyway, if updating to the latest PgJDBC (you failed to specify your version) doesn't help, what you need to do is `SET statement_timeout` *before* your query, then reset it after the query. Just execute:

```
SET statement_timeout = '5s';
```

or whatever before your query. If you're running it within an already open transaction you can use `SET LOCAL` to make the setting transaction scoped.

Comment: Craig, I am using Postgrs 9.2 and using mapped xml for insert queries as <insert id="someId" parameterType="List">INSERT INTO Something () </insert>

Comment: @user1450574 Well, then you're going to have to use a more flexible framework, or (if the latest PgJDBC does not help) propose a patch to PgJDBC to do what you want.